# How to delete default route with iproute2

Tags: routing, openvpn, networkmanager

I used NetworkManager to connect to a openVPN server. It is configured such that all traffic passes through the VPN:

```
> ip route                    
default via 10.4.4.73 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600
```

with 10.4.4.73 being the peer address of the tun0 device. The second route routes traffic through my local router. In an attempt to remove the default route, I issued the command:

```
ip route del default via 10.4.4.73 dev tun0
```

which does not throw an error, but does not alter the routing table neither. What is the right way to remove that route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ip route del` command looks not wrong to me. If it doesn't work, you either have to specify all properties or the route (that is, everything that `ip route show` prints, including 'metric' and 'proto') or you might get away with it by omitting the 'via' part.

Anyway, if you do this, NetworkManager may restore the route later and it certainly restores it upon re-activating the OpenVPN connection.

Probably, you should do
`nmcli connection modify $OVPN_CONN_NAME ipv4.never-default yes`

See `man nm-settings`.

Comment: I found that my command actually deleted the route, but NetworkManager discovered that and quickly set it up again. BTW, the option "ipv4.never-default yes" corresponds to the checkbox "Use this connection only for resources on its network' in NetworkManager's connection-editor

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the solution. Debian 12, KDE. NetworkManager doesn't have any checkbox mentioned by @jan. The syntax is slightly different `nmcli connection modify MyFortiVPNConnName ipv4.never-default yes`. [nmcli manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/network-manager/nmcli.1.en.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem deleting a default route that was added for a second interface upon boot. The correct command with the proper selector is the following:

```
ip route del to default via 192.168.0.1
```

That will delete only the route on the 192.168.0.1 interface.
The op was missing "to" as the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to see if it is an openvpn configuration or a network-manager parameter.

The `redirect-gateway` option can be pushed by server or setup by client config,  you have just to remove/comment it.

For network-manager, see that [serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/a/469131/168959)